# Calling PythonAPI prompts "failed toobtain a connection from pool within 60s" in Galaxybase

Tags: python, graph-databases

Here's the python code I used:

```
import pymysql

for i in range(150):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='username', password='password', db='test')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

And it returns: failed toobtain a connection from pool within 60s

Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the connection pool is full, and the default size of the connection pool is 100. If the return value of the API is iterator or cypher query results, it will occupy a connection.